# libusb-1.0 Seg Default libusb_device_descriptor

Tags: pointers, segmentation-fault, libusb-1.0

Notice:

I think I figured out why its not working.  It was the line libusb_device_handle**.  I am trying to create multiple handles.  Is this correct or am I only allowed one handle. Is it because I am using pointers wrong?  Do I need to create multiple contexts for separate devices?

Using libusb-1.0 am trying to get the device descriptor for a usb device.  The code compiles and no error messages are displayed, but it ends in a segmentation default.  I have narrow it down to a cause.  Opening a libusb_device and declaring a libusb_device_descriptor variable causes the seg fault.

```
#include <libusb.h>

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    libusb_context* context;

    libusb_device** devices;

    libusb_device_handle** handles;

    libusb_device_descriptor descriptor;

    libusb_init(&context);

    libusb_set_debug(context,LIBUSB_LOG_LEVEL_WARNING);

    int count = libusb_get_device_list(context,&devices);

    for(int i = 0u; i < count; ++i)
    {
        libusb_open(devices[i],&handles[i]);

        libusb_close(handles[i]);
    }
    libusb_free_device_list(devices,1);

    libusb_exit(context);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I fiddle around with it and figure something out.  I think it has something to do with how I am using pointers.  Using libusb_device_handle* works fine.  I am able to get the device descriptor.

Comment: So am I restricted to only using one device at a time with this handle or can I create multiple handles and i am just creating them wrong?